# ¿Cómo puedo bloquear en Windows 10 la ejecución de programas a un usuario en concreto?

Tags: windows, windows10

Necesito saber como puedo bloquear la ejecución de un programa cualquiera a un usuario en concreto.
Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias lograrlo con una entrada en la registry

[How to Block an Application or .EXE from Running in Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/180803/how-to-block-an-application-or-.exe-from-running-in-windows/)

o si la pc esta dentro de un dominio de windows podrias usar GPO (group policy)

[Allow Users To Run Only Specified Programs in Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8739/restrict-users-to-run-only-specified-programs-in-windows-7/)

[Blocking built-in apps in Windows 10 using Applocker](http://ccmexec.com/2015/08/blocking-built-in-apps-in-windows-10-using-applocker/)

Con la ayuda de `Applocker` puedes determinar a que usuario o grupo aplicas la restriccion, pero debes tener la pc en un dominio de windows para poder aplicar la policy.

Comment: Gracias por responder tan rápido.